# Update the database ios

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I have a database in my application, how can I get live updates? I mean how not to download the whole new database but just get the new records when pressing the update bu? any ideas? I've seen things like that in the news apps. WHat is the basic architecture?

Comment: Where is the data for the updates coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite the loaded question. Unfortunately it is much more complex than just what database to use. For local storage options you have SQLite and CoreData. Those are basically your 2 options for large amounts of data. Keeping those data sources in sync is something you will have to work out on your own. Who is providing the data? What format is it in? What are you going to do with your data locally to determine its update level? How will you check to make sure your data is up-to-date before trying to send information?

This is a very large problem that will definitely need to be looked at before you attempt to build your app and data structures. I'm sorry there isn't a simple answer for your question. StackOverflow is great place to get specific answers to specific questions, but you are asking a very vague question to a very complex issue. Hopefully some of these questions I'm asking you back will help lead you in the right direction. Good luck.

Comment: Hello, I use SQLite, I get data in json and put it in the sqlite database with my own model. How can I determine update level? That's what I don't know either. I don't know how to update certain records in the db tables for example. How can I keep my data in sync? I've already gone far with sqlite.... Each time I will be downloading a new database(( but that's terrible( How can synchronize? please help me, it's a complicated application I'm making and I had few time for it. Thanks...

Comment: I won't be able to help too much, but we have something similar at my job where we add a row to the table called exchangeLevel. It is just an integer that gets incremented when data changes. This happens on both ends. Data on server changes, update the exchange level. Then just pull data or ship data that doesn't match the system wide exchangeLevel. It isn't a perfect system, but you will probably have to implement something similar if you don't want to send everything every time.

Comment: Thanks... but how do they implement that so seamlessly in applications like TED, leParisien where there are update button/drag-table-gesture and the data is succesfully updated and stored for displaying when there's no internet connection? there is also preload of the earlier records... They say it's easy and classical, but I never did anything like that...